# removing header from top output

Tags: bash, logging, awk, sed, process

I want to write some process data to a file. To do this, I'm choosing to use `top`. I want to monitor several processes and plot a graph of their performance overtime.

I'm using Mac OS 10.12. I don't think there's an easy way to get the version number.

right now I have the command:

`top -l 2 -n 5 -o mem | awk '{ printf("%-8s  %-12s  %-6s %-6s\n", $1, $2, $3, $8); }'`

which results in the following output:

```
Processes:  390           total, 2015
2017/09/15  00:41:51
Load      Avg:          2.07,
CPU       usage:        5.11%  idle
SharedLibs:  169M          resident,
MemRegions:  117317        total, 1807M
PhysMem:  15G           used
VM:       2149G         vsize, swapins,
Networks:  packets:      24606796/21G
Disks:    2934900/103G  read,

PID       COMMAND       %CPU   MEM
0         kernel_task   0.0    1594M+
94178     idea          0.0    897M+
621       Google        Chrome 1
277       Google        Chrome 3865+
31724     Slack         Helper 223+
Processes:  390           total, 2021
2017/09/15  00:41:52
Load      Avg:          2.07,
CPU       usage:        4.47%  idle
SharedLibs:  169M          resident,
MemRegions:  117317        total, 1807M
PhysMem:  15G           used
VM:       2149G         vsize, swapins,
Networks:  packets:      24606796/21G
Disks:    2934900/103G  read,

PID       COMMAND       %CPU   MEM
0         kernel_task   3.9    1594M-
94178     idea          1.3    897M
621       Google        Chrome 1
277       Google        Chrome 3866+
31724     Slack         Helper 223
```

However, I want to remove the headers and be left with:

```
PID       COMMAND       %CPU   MEM
0         kernel_task   0.0    1594M+
94178     idea          0.0    897M+
621       Google        Chrome 1
277       Google        Chrome 3865+
31724     Slack         Helper 223+
0         kernel_task   3.9    1594M-
94178     idea          1.3    897M
621       Google        Chrome 1
277       Google        Chrome 3866+
31724     Slack         Helper 223
```

for all of the batches. I'm also ok with omitting the `PID COMMAND %CPU MEM` line.

I've tried piping into `sed` but the following command

`top -l 2 -n 5 -o mem | sed '1,10d;n;' | awk '{ printf("%-8s  %-12s  %-6s %-6s\n", $1, $2, $3, $8); }'`

only deletes the first 10 rows, not the first 10 rows of EACH iteration. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: As a suggestion: because pid's show up more than once, you could just print the last occurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**awk** solution.

one liner:

```
top -l 2 -n 5 -o mem | awk '/^PID/{if (p) next; p=1} p && NF>30 {printf("%-8s  %-12s  %-6s %-6s\n", $1, $2, $3, $8)}'
```

explanation:

```
/^PID/{                    # line starts with PID
  if (p) next;             # if this is second time around, skip
  p=1                      # else: set var p to 1
} 
p && NF>30 {               # if p is set and number of fields > 30, print         
  printf("%-8s  %-12s  %-6s %-6s\n", $1, $2, $3, $8)
}
```

output:

```
 $ top -l 2 -n 5 -o mem | awk '/^PID/{if (p) next; p=1} p && NF>30 {printf("%-8s  %-12s  %-6s %-6s\n", $1, $2, $3, $8) }'
 PID       COMMAND       %CPU   MEM
 0         kernel_task   0.0    1950M+
 320       idea          0.0    1007M+
 14246     thunderbird   0.0    541M+
 3142      Google        Chrome 1
 3136      Google        Chrome 2153+
 0         kernel_task   2.0    1950M-
 320       idea          3.1    1007M
 14246     thunderbird   0.0    541M
 3142      Google        Chrome 1
 3136      Google        Chrome 2153
```

And now you know what my mail client is.